# Delete all rows with a certain reference if specific text in another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have tried numerous solutions for this but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Under column "N" is a 8-digit reference number. Under column "L" is a single word - for argument let's say either X or Y.

There can be numerous rows with the same reference number but different data in all other columns.

I am trying to delete all rows that have the same reference number IF each row has the word X in column L. Any reference numbers that have any rows with the word Y shouldn't be deleted.

The data tab is a minimum of 50,000 rows.

Can anyone help with this please?

Many thanks.

I've tried numerous solutions but I can't seem to find a way to refer back to the same reference number.

Small solutions like the below can delete rows with same specific words but how I can adapt this to only do so if they all have the same reference number I just don't know.

```
For r = Sheet3.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "L") = "Y" Then
            Sheet3.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Add a helper column to your data to check for the records you want to delete and then use it to filter to just the rows you want to delete.       =AND(LEN([Column L cell])<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE([Column L cell] ,"x","")),COUNTIF([Reference cell Column],[reference cell])>0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this could take a LONG time to run! Suggest running on a sample of your data first. Also note that when this finds 'column N duplicates', it will leave the last of those present in the Sheet.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, lLastRow As Long
    ' assuming the Worksheet you want to work on is 'Sheet3'
    Set wks = Sheet3
    lLastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "N").End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    
    Dim collNumbers As Collection, lRow As Long
    Set collNumbers = New Collection
    
    For lRow = lLastRow To 1 Step -1
        ' change "X" to the correct word
        ' if you want the comparison to "X" to be case-insensitive then change vbBinaryCompare to vbTextCompare
        If StrComp(CStr(wks.Cells(lRow, "L").Value), "X", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            If Not AddIfUnique(collNumbers, CStr(wks.Cells(lRow, "N").Value)) Then
                wks.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents ' so that you can 'break into' the code if required
    Next lRow
End Sub


Private Function AddIfUnique(coll As Collection, sText As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add sText, sText
    AddIfUnique = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

The DeleteRows() Sub cycles through each row from the last row in which column N has a value up to row 1, checking the value in column L and passing the value in column N to the AddIfUnique() Function which tests whether we have already seen that value (i.e. the value in column N) by trying to add it to a Collection using that value as the Collection key. Collection keys must be unique, hence if adding to the Collection fails then we have seen that key (and so that value in column N) already and the row is then deleted.

> Revised answer for clarified requirement per comments

As with the 'original solution', this could take a LONG time to run ... test on a sample first.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Const lFIRST_ROW_OF_DATA As Long = 2 ' assuming row 1 is always a header row
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet, lLastRow As Long
    
    Set wks = Sheet3 ' assuming the Worksheet you want to work on is 'Sheet3'
    lLastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "N").End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    
    Dim collNumbers As Collection, lRow As Long
    Set collNumbers = New Collection
    
    For lRow = lFIRST_ROW_OF_DATA To lLastRow
        ' change "Y" to the correct word
        ' if you want the comparison to "Y" to be case-insensitive then change vbBinaryCompare to vbTextCompare
        If StrComp(CStr(wks.Cells(lRow, "L").Value), "Y", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            AddIfUnique collNumbers, CStr(wks.Cells(lRow, "N").Value)
        End If
        DoEvents ' so that you can 'break into' the code if required
    Next lRow
    
    For lRow = lLastRow To lFIRST_ROW_OF_DATA Step -1
        If Not IsPresent(collNumbers, CStr(wks.Cells(lRow, "N").Value)) Then
            wks.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        DoEvents ' so that you can 'break into' the code if required
    Next lRow
End Sub

Private Function AddIfUnique(coll As Collection, sText As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add sText, sText
    AddIfUnique = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function

Private Function IsPresent(coll As Collection, sText As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim v As Variant
    v = coll.Item(sText)
    IsPresent = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Note this assumes that row 1 contains headers and so row 2 is the first row of data ... if not correct, adjust the value for the `lFIRST_ROW_OF_DATA` Const. Also just to point out that the test for what is in column L is now for "Y" not "X" so be aware of that when updating this to use the real word.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion - however there seems to be an issue with this. It's deleting some rows that it shouldn't be. It looks like whenever it sees a case with multiple rows with the word "Y" it reduces them to one row - even though they should all be spared as there's a row with the word "X" under that reference number in column N. It also isn't deleting most rows that should be deleted. Some are correctly deleted but many that only have rows with the word "Y" under their contact ref are spared for some reason.

Comment: I re-tested on the dummy data I used and works as described. Make sure you have changed 'X' to the word that indicates potential deletion (not the word that indicates the row should be saved) and change `vbBinaryCompare` to `vbTextCompare` if the word can be in different cases. Also note the comment that the last (lowest) of the duplicate rows (where 'X') is left as-is, not the first.

Comment: I've changed X to the desired word and tried both vbBinaryCompare and vbTextCompare but still no luck. Maybe I've explained things wrong - sorry about that. I've attached a link to a copy of a test spreadsheet I've been using (password is a9@2S1{!s ). The rows in orange should be deleted and the rows in red should be spared but when running the macro this doesn't line up. Any thoughts? Thanks again! https://thomascarroll-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/luke_twinney_thomas-carroll_co_uk/EUFAfFIWLtVGgdwILMgiuR8Beqj7LHOeHVoPAUOX6QFzqw?e=IWj7aZ

Comment: Can you delete the code in the shared workbook and save it as a .xlsx (not .xlsm)

Comment: Yeah of course, here you go: https://thomascarroll-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/luke_twinney_thomas-carroll_co_uk/EdToh2GwlutKvkzHMFQduFMBw13PJ6i5ymH7TsfsEyll9w?e=9O5siU

Comment: So ran the code on that sheet and it works as per my understanding of your requirements. Maybe you can clarify your needs as I cannot understand the link between the rows you have highlighted orange and the requirements you describe in the question? Also try this: comment-out the `wks.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete` line and insert, immediately following it, `wks.Rows(lRow).Resize(1, 14).Font.Bold = True` - this will now not delete rows but make them bold font, making it easier for you to see what is happening. Remember the algorithm, as it stands, works from the end of the populated rows upwards

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try clarifying here. We look at the Contact Ref number in Column N and see every row with that number (the data is ordered by contact ref). If each row with that number has the word "X" in Column L then delete all the rows. If any of the rows with that number have the word "Y" in column L, then none of the rows with that reference number should be deleted. In the first set of red rows for instance, there is X, Y and X under the number 10355222. Since there is a Y, none of the rows with 10355222 should be deleted. Does that make sense? Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Updated answer for clarified requirement

Answer (score 0):

This code sort the database, so if it is not convenient or has some other issue let me know.
Delete, if column L cells' values all are "Y" or "y" for a specific ref.number.

```
Sub eliminator()
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Range("L1").End(xlDown).Row
ws.Range("L1:N" & lastrow).Sort ws.Columns("N")
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    pn = ws.Cells(i, "N")
    j = i - 1
    If UCase(ws.Cells(i, "L")) = "Y" Then del = True Else del = False
    If j <> 0 Then
        Do While ws.Cells(j, "N") = pn
            If UCase(ws.Cells(j, "L")) = "Y" Then
            ElseIf del = True Then
                del = False
            End If
            j = j - 1
        Loop
    If j = i - 1 Then del = False
    End If
    If del Then ws.Range(ws.Rows(i), ws.Rows(j + 1)).Delete: i = j + 1
    
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion as well however running this doesn't seem to do anything on my sheet. Am I missing something?

Comment: The activesheet must be the sheet where the data are when you start the macro.

Comment: If your datasheet is Sheet3, replace `Set ws = ActiveSheet` with `Set ws = Sheet3`. In this case can start from any of the sheets is active.